# Grails - Calling scripts within DB Migration changelog

Tags: grails, liquibase

While using the DB Migration plugin I came across an interesting question. In our regular war deployments, time and again, we need to run certain scripts for data updates to accommodate our changed code. While we can still run these externally, we were trying to find a way to add them as a part of DB Migration process.

Now one set of these scripts can be converted into migration scripts and added inside the grailsChange section and and they run pretty seamlessly. There is another set of scripts though, which are problematic because of a couple of reasons.

1. These scripts are run time and again so we would have to keep changing the id with every run as we don't want to duplicate the code, thus losing the original changes.
2. We pass params to these scripts from the command line and by the method above we have to add them to the scripts themselves just causing maintainability issues.

So my question would be, is there a more elegant way to trigger external grails or groovy scripts from within the DB migration scripts such that every time we need to run a script file, we can create the changelog with the updated call and tag it with the app.

I think there was a post on stackoverflow regarding this a while back, but I cannot for the love of my life, find it any more. Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are the scripts something you could add into bootstrap.groovy? That would probably be the simplest. Just use groovy.sql.Sql to run the scripts.

Another more functional and flexible option would be to create a service to run the scripts (groovy.sql.Sql) and a domain class to track the scripts that have been run. You could trigger the service in the bootstrap.groovy file and the service could look at some migrations domain class you set up to see if the script has been run. You could even go as far to secure a front end to this mechanism to upload a script file to execute at runtime.

Let me know more details of what you want and I can try to be more detailed in my response.